# Tableview inside a ViewController in container view changes layout on rotate

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview, cgsize

I kept a tableview inside a viewController.ViewController is inside a  container view.

The problem is that the layout changes on rotation of the device.
This is not a constraint issue as it happens only on rotation.

here's what i have done

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{

    CGSize contentSize = self.affiliationListTableView.contentSize;
    contentSize.width = self.affiliationListTableView.superview.superview.superview.bounds.size.width;
  //  contentSize.height = self.affiliationListTableView.superview.bounds.size.height;
    self.affiliationListTableView.contentSize = contentSize;


}
```

I have noticed that the contentSize is varying on rotation.Is it a bug from apple side? If we are using a UITableViewController instead of UIViewController,this is not happening.But requirement doesn't allow me to use UITableViewController

[image: view on portrait initially]

[image: view after rotation]

Please provide any suggestions/thoughts